# How do I create a northern continent in my world?

Tags: geology

Basically I want to create a large land-mass in my world that is located in the northern hemisphere (I'm not sure whether to make it arctic or more Finland-like or what) 
I'm having a really hard time deciding on how to draw it and make it more or less scientifically accurate. I'd really like some tips as I'm totally new to this.
(I did read about Geology but sadly it doesn't help much.)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Worldbuilding! Can you please clarify what your continent is for? Do you want to populate it with specific species? Do you need a mapping software to draw it on map?

Comment: Hi Mellow!  Welcome to Worldbuilding! There are so many different ways that we might answer your question, it's difficult to choose a "best answer" (which is important around here).  Deciding what you want the continent to do and how you want to use it will go a long way towards helping you make headway.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/program-for-simulating-planets/97292#97292

Comment: >Cold/Arctic continent that doesn't really have any close neighbors (Perhaps Taiga type) 
>Pockets of humanity spread out and thin on it (How did they get there and why do humans exist in the first place?)
>Whaling and mammoths are the main reasons humans are able to survive
>Perhaps a central tyrannic city-state that was able to prosper thanks to better climate conditions and exploits the whole continent
>I checked out deities and gods as for now
>Humans are able to wield fire magic (Exclusively magic as of now, not sure how I'm making magic even work yet)

Comment: Also, an 'on-hold' question isn't the end.  You can clarify the question so it's not so broad then vote to reopen it.  If you have more questions, you can pop over to chat and ask there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor

Comment: Since you've already done something or at least tried, why don't you share what you've got so far?

Comment: The notes I have above are pretty much all I have, I just want an icy grim setting to plunge my mind into from time to time. Might be similar to ASOIAF in it's atmosphere.

Comment: @Mellow - imagine Northern Europe/[Fennoscandia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fennoscandia) is a continent on its own. Would it fit your idea?

Comment: I suppose it would work

Comment: North America has just about every type of terrain imaginable. That's the nice thing about continent sized land masses ... there's room for everything.

Comment: @Green Mellow won't have access to chat yet.  Requires 20 rep.

Comment: @James  Ooops.  I forgot about that.

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your question to include additional details, such as those you left in comments above. Comments aren't guaranteed to hang around, so if the detail is intended to clarify the question, it's best to include in the question itself. Also, you can notify one user per comment using the '@<username>' syntax.